# Modify grub setting ina live cd->/etc/defalt/grub doesn't exist and I have a nearly black screen just grub is written and freezed on a macbookpro 2009

Tags: grub2, macbook-pro, macosx

I would like how, for exemple, give the nomodeset parameter to grub in a live cd configuration. The only file I found is /boot/grub.cfg and the presentation of the file is not the same as in a normal installed version. I mean dont know how to do a grub-update as the /etc/default/grub file doesn't exist.

How to do the same in a "live" version as in an "installed" version
where is the equivalence of files.

Thanx
(I assume the problem of the black screen could come from a display driver ..?) I have a black screen with only grub written and its frozen.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; as the key that achieves it varies on release & ISO being used. Some allow you to add it to `grub` just like it was an installed system, but what Ubuntu product/ISO/release are you asking about?

Comment: Either press Shift when booting or press e, (to edit GRUB menu). It will not be permanent. If you want to be able to permanently edit grub.cfg on an installer USB, make the USB using Rufus or UNetbootin in Windows or mkusb in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello,
sorry in fact I made a mistake. 
I used Debian 10 and 11 .. I tried 8 but only 9 natively worked (efi and grub displayed normaly). 
Yep I know the stuff with the alt button but when i select UEFI boot i get a black screen and it's fully frozen.. 
No keyboard input possible.. I read that it could be nomodeset or a gpu driver issu so I asked for that.. 

I solved my problem by installing Debian 9 and upgrade it to Debian 10.. Wich still support nvidia driver 340xx (nevertheless once installed I used the one provided by Linux nonfree and Misc i think.. anyway the default one)

Comment: I tried ubuntu ... 20 i think later and the issue came from the fact */boot/* could not be found / loaded.. I used etcher to create the usb live key.

The main question for me in fact was how can i give an option at grub on a live usb key .. as the filetree isn't the same than in "normal" installation.. And to know if it is possible and how.. 

Thank for your answer

But when i arrive on the first grub screen its frozen so I can't use keyboard at all I need to reboot and try another distrib

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.